# Can server_hostname in python wrap_socket holds IPv4 string value?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, network-programming, tls1.2

I understand that `server_hostname` parameter in the `wrap_socket` function in the `ssl.SSLContext()` object as in the example below can be used to identify a hostname when a single server hosts several host names. Can the `server_hostname` be used or does it make sense to use the `server_hostname` parameter with a value that is not a string of a hostname but a string for an IPv4 address?

1) Is there is any use, or advantage that makes my connection more accurate (for the specified IP)?

2) Can a server hosts many virtual IPs such that specifying an IPv4 address in the `server_hostname` adds value?

This example from python [websites](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ssl.html)

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='www.verisign.com')
ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_hostname` is used to enable SNI "Server Name Indication", so it needs to be an hostname and can not be an IP address.

This is exactly in order to be able to provide TLS service for multiple hostnames (think websites) all running on the same server and hence IP address. TLS handshake (and hence certificates exchanges) happens before any kind of data level exchanges, where an hostname could give an hint (like the `host` header in HTTP), hence we need SNI in TLS to convey that information.

And all good behaving clients should provide this information during TLS handshake, otherwise they risk hitting the wrong service or getting back the wrong certificates.